# Update column in table where a specific character appears

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a table in my database where a specific character appears but can't get it to work correctly. So where '/' appears add an additional '/'.

I have added my code below.

Here is the table that I want to update.

Table1

| FirstName | LastName | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Smith | 25 /Long Lane/ Surrey |

Desired Output:

| FirstName | LastName | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam | Smith | 25 //Long Lane// Surrey |

SQL that isn't working:

I have the below update statement which isn't working. It just adds '/' a the start of the column which isn't correct. It is not getting me the desired output.

```
update table 
set Address = '/' + Address
where Address like '%/%'
```

Comment: When posting [tag:sql] questions, please also tag the specific RDBMS you’re working with - in many contexts this can materially impact the answers you get.

Answer (score 2):

Seems simple enough:
*(Assuming Microsoft SQL Server)*

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET Address = REPLACE(Address, '/', '//')
WHERE Address Like '%/%';
```

However, you should consider what happens if you run this against an already-escaped value. Each `//` will be replaced with `////`.

Comment: ANSI SQL compliant too!

Answer (score 0):

Why not `REPLACE()` instances of `/` with `//`…?

```
update table 
set Address = REPLACE(Address, '/', '//')
```